# Applescript search and delete specific Mac Text Messages

Tags: macos, applescript, messages, shortcuts-app, spam

Hackers have daily targeted my **Mac Messages** app. I get a dozen or so messages daily from similar but slightly differing handles.

For example:
[image: Screenshot of targeted spam]

All of the handles using an email address has consistently utilized "pqe@icloud.com" at the end of the address. Yet, last week, these hackers are now using phone numbers too. So I can't programatically search for messages by handle now that email *and* phone number is used.

**However**, *the message body copy is the same*:

> "Hello there"

Can I use actionscript to specifically target any message with "Hello there" string, then delete it without all the modal windows asking if I am sure, or if I want to report spam? And also a schedule the script to run every minute or so?

Thank you so much!

Bruce

Comment: More like spammers than hackers. They may have hacked some messaging system and/or mail server, but unless they are attacking your devices, they are merely spammers at your end.

Comment: Ahhh! I am being inundated!!!

Comment: I am now running MacOS 13 Ventura. Some small changes are welcome. You can finally filter by known users etc. (like the iPhone). You can also shift click for multiple selections / to delete all at once.

BUT!

How do I filter these spammers? I get 30 a day. Ugh.

Comment: Check to see what addresses you have set up to accept messages. For example, I only send/receive message with my iPhone's cell number, not my iCloud address. It's in your messages settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting the exact same messages - about 30 per day, from random looking iCloud addresses which usually take the form of *name.random-characters.pqe@icloud.com*, but can also be cellphone numbers. They mostly arrive during the evening and overnight. I've tried "Report Junk" but it doesn't seem to do anything, and blocking the sender doesn't work because it's rarely the same sender twice. It's really frustrating!

[image]

Short of contacting Apple support the best thing to do is to keep reporting them as spam in the app.

Comment: How is this an answer instead of a comment? What am I missing? I too want to be able to delete messages via script, albeit for a different reason (security cam pics that my pi sends me).